# Memory allocation error with GSL ODE solver applied to system of 4 ODEs

Tags: linear-solver, c++, ode, memory-management

I am trying to solve a (large) system of ODEs with GSL solvers. When I use driver method I get an error message of `could not allocate space for gsl_interp_accel`, when I define control, error and stepper manually, I get `bad_alloc` exception, which is caused, as far as I understand it, by the same thing that causes `could not allocate space for gsl_interp_accel` in the other case - the lack of memory.

I have consulted with other `bad_alloc` queries, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378797/stdbad-alloc-am-i-using-too-much-memory), but I haven't found anything useful for my particular case there. Also, I have tried other ODE solvers, but they also end up with memory errors. I have also checked my program with valgrind to make sure there are no memory errors/leaks anywhere else apart from the solver.

Any solver has "limits of integration", and in my case program works fine for about 10% of the upper limit (which is large comparing to lower limit - I am pretty sure this is the source of errors I get - but I do need to integrate between these particular limits) and then terminates with one of the exceptions I've quoted above. I have tried various (fixed/adaptive) step size, but never reached more than 10% of what I want.

The piece of code that gives an exception is:

```
gsl_ode_struct inputstruct;  // Struct that contains parameters for ODEs 
gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {func, NULL, 2*G.getsize(), &inputstruct};
const gsl_odeiv2_step_type * T = gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd;
gsl_odeiv2_step * stepper = gsl_odeiv2_step_alloc (T, size_of_the_system);
gsl_odeiv2_control * control = gsl_odeiv2_control_standard_new (1.e-6, 0.0, 1., 0.);
gsl_odeiv2_evolve * error = gsl_odeiv2_evolve_alloc (size_of_the_system);
double hparam = 1.e-6; // Initial step size
double t = xspan[0]; // Initial time
while(t < final_time){
    // Here the excpection comes
    int status = gsl_odeiv2_evolve_apply (error, control, stepper, &sys, &t, final_time, &hparam, array);
    if(status != GSL_SUCCESS)
        break;
    // Do some stuff that includes reading all the intermediate results to a container as I need them later.
    }
    gsl_odeiv2_evolve_free (error);
    gsl_odeiv2_control_free (control);
    gsl_odeiv2_step_free (stepper);
```

So if I change `final_time` to `final_time/10` code executes, but the result then does not make any sense. Even when nothing is done after solver, exception is still thrown, `could not allocate space for gsl_interp_accel`, though.

I have tried to split the loop on several (many) loops with erasing memory in between, but this didn't help much.

In case this is important, I use Ubuntu 12.10, compiled with GNU compiler and Intel C++ Composer. Also tested on Mac (don't know which version of OS) with the same result.

The question is: is there any way to "cheat" on the solver and make the program work properly?

P.S.: ODEint solver, that has smarter way of getting intermediate results, also throws an exception.

Comment: It's likely that you just don't have enough RAM for this problem. How big is your ODE system? How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have checked the memory usage and this is true. Is there any way to beat it apart from buying more memory? I have 4GB and 4 equations but on very big range.

Comment: If you can't get more RAM or more computers (and a distributed-memory parallel ODE solver), then you might look for an out-of-core ODE solver. This will probably run at least 10 if not 100 times slower than a problem that fits in memory.

Comment: If you only have 4 equations, it shouldn't take this much memory -- unless you somehow store the solution of every time step and try to get them all into memory at the same time. If that's not what you are doing, then you have a memory leak. Try running your code with valgrind to find out where it is.

Comment: Wolfgang has a good point. If it's only 4 equations, you should write out intermediate time steps as you go. You should then only need to store a handful of values.

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly what I do and what I need to do. Valgrind gives no memory leaks, by the way. I have been advised to output these values to the file, but I doubt if it helps, as the code breaks down even if I do not store intermediate steps. Thank you all for your answers, I will try to do something with out-of-core solver tomorrow.

Comment: @Bill Barth, could you, please, recommend any out-of-core ODE solver?

Comment: Seriously, you're barking up the wrong tree if you think out-of-core solvers are the way to go. I don't know GSL, so I can't say what's the problem here but for such a small system there is absolutely no reason for it not to work with 4kB, let alone 4GB...